# How to get full product image url in Magento

Tags: magento

How to get full product image url in **magento** ,i need to migrate the data from magento to  **django** so i need to get the product **full image url** to migrate the site

here is my code

```
<?php
@ob_start();
@session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//for order update
include '../../../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
echo '<pre>';
if(isset($_REQUEST['productid'])){
$productId = $_REQUEST['productid'];
}else{
echo 'Default Product => ';
$productId = '12402'; // product ID 10 is an actual product, and used here for a test
}
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);  //load the product     

print_r($product->getthumbnail());<br/>
print_r($product->getcreated_at());
?>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try below code
first of all call helper of catalog

```
echo  Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');
```

From this code you can get cache path also.

Comment: Hi by using this code i get following error        Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /mnt/aviesta/development/webApps/migration/productapi/new/index.php on line 24

Answer (score 19):

After you loaded your product using `load()` you can use the following in your code:

Full size image:

```
$imageUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
```

Resized/Cached image:

```
$imageCacheUrl = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(135, 135);
```

If you need a different cache size, then use other numbers for the resize method.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer and link with my code , i dont know how to link this with my code, my code is in a webdev directoey

Comment: i need the full cache path also for the image , i am trying very hard but have no idea how to get this

Comment: @RohitGoel I updated my post. Add my code right after your $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); line.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$full_path_url = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_products, 'small_image')->resize(200,200);?>" width="200" alt=""> 

    <?php ini_set('display_errors','on');
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app('default');
    $_products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->toOptionArray();
    $product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $_products=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);?>
```